# Ajax functions - no access to wp-admin.php only online

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, front-end

I'm having some trouble with my custom ajax function.
I have this on my console log :
"POST MYSITEURL/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 302 Found". So my functions won't work...

And I really don't understand why.

I've developed a login form for the front end, it works well on my local but not online.
Here is what I do :

```
function ajax_login_init(){
//First I register my scripts
    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery'),'',true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');
//I give them variables
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => '/account'
    ));

}

function allowAjaxLogin(){
//I allow the function
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_priv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );

}
add_action( 'init','allowAjaxLogin' );


if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}

function ajax_login(){
// First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );
    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username/password')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Success)));
    }

    die();
}
```

As I said, it works well on my local version, but not online, someone can help me?

Comment: Stuff like this belongs in a plugin... and `get_temlate_directory_uri()` tells me you're using it in a theme.

Comment: Indeed, I'll try to write this as a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found why !

It was because I have 2 domain, (.com / .be)

When I update my online DataBase, I have to point to .be and not .com. It's now working !

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the file owner for wp-admin, it could be that it's own by different user and it won't allow you to read.

Check permission of the file if it's readable by world

Comment: I guess you're talking about CHMOD ? The file (admin-ajax.php) can be readable for the public, and it's still not working..

Comment: Nobody can tell me why it isn't working?